# Precision on FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

I am trying to solve a non linear system of equation, and when I solve it, I have the following message

`FindRoot::lstol`: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

Because of the lack of precision, I'm not sure of my result and changing the iterations and accuracy changes nothing.

Here is my code:

```
E1 = 0.53*10^9;
k1 = 0.269*10^(-6);
K1 = 0.5;
α1 = 30*10^(-6);
ν1 = 0.25;
μ1 = E1/(2 (1 + ν1));

E2 = 125*10^9;
k2 = 12.98*10^(-6);
K2 = 54;
α2 = 12*10^(-6);
ν2 = 0.5;
μ2 = E2/(2 (1 + ν2));
k = k1/k2;
K = K1/K2;
α = α1 (1 + ν1)/(α2 (1 + ν2));
f = 0.4;

ξ1[c1_] := Sqrt[0.5 (1 + Sqrt[1 + (c1/k)^2])];
ξ2[c2_] := Sqrt[0.5 (1 + Sqrt[1 + (c2)^2])];
η1[c1_] := -Sqrt[0.5 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + (c1/k)^2])];
η2[c2_] := Sqrt[0.5 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + c2^2])];
H1asym[A_] := 
  2 *μ1* μ2* 
   k2* α2* (1 + ν2)/ (K2 (μ2 (1 - ν1) (-A Csch[
              A]^2 + Coth[A]) + μ1 (1 - ν2) Coth[A]^2));
H2asym[A_] := 
  4*μ1 *μ2 *
   k2 *α2 *(1 + ν2)/(K2 (μ2 (1 - 
           2 ν1) (-A Csch[A]^2 + Coth[A]) - μ1 (1 - 
           2 ν2) Coth[A] - μ1 A Csch[A]^2));
Hasym[A_] := H1asym[A] / H2asym[A]; 

M1 [ c2_, 
   A_] := (ξ2 [c2] Sinh[2 A ξ2[c2]] + η2[c2] Sin[
       2 A η2[c2]])/(Cosh[2 A ξ2[c2]] - Cos[2 A η2[c2]]);
M2[c2_, A_] := (η2[c2] Sinh[2 A ξ2[c2]] - ξ2[c2] Sin[
       2 A η2[c2]])/(Cosh[2 A ξ2[c2]] - Cos[2 A η2[c2]]);
M3[c1_, A_] := α (- A Csch[A]^2 + Coth[A])/ ξ1[c1];
M4[c2_, A_] := (Coth[
      A]/(ξ2[c2] η2[c2])) (η2[c2] Sinh[
        2 A ξ2[c2]] - ξ2[c2] Sin[2 A η2[c2]])/(Cosh[
       2 A ξ2[c2]] - Cos[2 A η2[c2]]);
N1[c2_, A_] := ( -ξ2[c2] Sin[2 A η2[c2]] + η2[c2] Sinh[
       2 A ξ2[c2]])/ (Cosh[2 A ξ2[c2]] - Cos[2 A η2[c2]]);
N2[c2_, A_] := (ξ2[c2] Sinh[2 A ξ2[c2]] + η2[c2] Sin[
       2 A η2[c2]])/(Cosh[2 A ξ2[c2]] - Cos[2 A η2[c2]]);
N3[c1_, A_] := ( α η1[
       c1] / (ξ1[c1] (ξ1[c1] + 1))) (-A Csch[A]^2 + Coth[A]);
N4[c2_, A_] := (Coth[
     A]/ (ξ2[c2] η2[
       c2])) ((ξ2[c2] Sinh[2 A ξ2[c2]] + η2[c2] Sin[
        2 A η2[c2]] - 
      Coth[A] (Cosh[2 A ξ2[c2]] - Cos[2 A η2[c2]]))/(Cosh[
       2 A ξ2[c2]] - Cos[2 A η2[c2]]))

V[c1_, c2_] := c1 - c2;
equation76 [c1_, c2_, A_] := 
  K ξ1[c1] + M1[c2, A] + 
    f Hasym[A] (K η1[c2] + M2[c2, A] ) -  
    f H1asym[A]/2 (M3[c1, A] + M4[c2, A])*(V[c1, c2]) == 0;

equation77[c1_, c2_, A_] := 
  K η1[c2] + N1[c2, A] - f Hasym[A] (K ξ1[c1] + N2[c2, A]) + 
    f H1asym[A]/2 (N3[c1, A] + N4[c2, A]) * (V[c1, c2]) == 0;

solasym[A_] := 
 FindRoot[{equation76[c1, c2, A], 
   equation77[c1, c2, A]}, {{c1, 10000}, {c2, 2}}, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000] 
Table[FindRoot[{equation76[c1, c2, A], 
   equation77[c1, c2, A]}, {{c1, 10000}, {c2, 2}}, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000] , {A, 0.1, 6 , .1}]
 

ListLinePlot[Table[{A, A*V[c1, c2] /. solasym[A]}, {A, 0.1, 6, .01}], 
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log"] // Quiet
```

Have you an idea how I can get better precision?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Rationalize both equations and apply higher WorkingPrecision to FindRoot.

Answer (score 1):

I am using MMA 12.1. If I run your code, I do not get any error messages.
As a result I get the following plot:
[image]

Comment: (1) There are error messages printed by the `Table` that precedes the `ListLinePlot`. (2) Isn't the reason you don't get errors using the OP's plotting code because the code suppresses the messages with `Quiet`? (I'm using V12.1.1.)

Comment: I did it without the Quiet[] and did get a long table and the above plot, but no error messages.

Comment: Odd, I got many error messages from the plot, two from the table.

Comment: I checked again. I have MMA 12.1.0.0 and the Windows version. By the way, did you restart the kernel. In case you have variables with values?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with a fresh kernel.  It's an odd difference, because the errors indicate a mathematical problem with the function. I would have thought bugs or differences related to evaluating functions would be extremely rare.

Comment: How good is your solution for `A = 0.1`? Differences between the sides of the equations are `{0.0000262183, 0.173075}` and the solution is `{c1 -> 20691.3, c2 -> 0.281772}`.

Comment: Very strange, today (that means shut down of PC) I also receive error messages about the step size from FindRoot. However, I get a slightly different result: {c1 -> 20691.3, c2 -> 0.281821}. I had another idea what could be wrong. Sometimes very strange behaviour was caused by an invisible character in the code.